# Custom attached property of ResourceDictionary with implicit declaration syntax?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties, attached-properties

As you know a FrameworkElement has a property of type `ResourceDictionary` named `Resources`, in XAML we can declare it easily like this:

```
 <FrameworkElement.Resources>
     <SomeObject x:Key="someKey"/>
     <SomeOtherObject x:Key="someOtherKey"/>
 </FrameworkElement.Resources>
```

It's some kind of implicit syntax, all the elements declared inside will be added to the `ResourceDictionary`. Now I would like to create an attached property having type of `ResourceDictionary`, of course a requirement of being notified when the property is changed is needed. Here is the code:

```
public static class Test
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TestProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Test", typeof(ResourceDictionary), 
                         typeof(Test), new PropertyMetadata(propertyChanged));
    public static ResourceDictionary GetTest(DependencyObject o)
    {
        return o.GetValue(TestProperty) as ResourceDictionary;
    }
    public static void SetTest(DependencyObject o, ResourceDictionary resource)
    {
        o.SetValue(TestProperty, resource);
    }
    static void propertyChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Usage in XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <local:Test.Test>
        <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="cl"></Style>
    </local:Test.Test>
</Grid>
```

Now if I run the code, an exception will be thrown saying `Test` property is null. I've tried providing a default instance for the attached property like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TestProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Test", typeof(ResourceDictionary), 
        typeof(Test), new PropertyMetadata(new ResourceDictionary(), propertyChanged));
```

Then it seems to run OK but there is not any change notification **initially**. It's very important to get the change notification at first so that I can proceed some handling.

Currently to achieve what I want, I have to let the default value as `null` and use it in XAML like this:

```
<local:Test.Test>
   <ResourceDictionary>
      <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="cl"></Style>
   </ResourceDictionary>
</local:Test.Test>
```

That works but not very convenient, I would like it to behave like what we can do with the `Resources` property of `FrameworkElement`. 
I hope someone here has some suggestion to solve this issue. I would be highly appreciated to receive any idea even something saying it's impossible (but of course you should be sure about that).

Comment: The change event is thrown because you don't change the property, but the content of the ResourceDictionary. Unfortunately there aren't any change notifications fired by the ResourceDictionary, so i would stay with the last snippet.

Comment: @SnowballTwo I don't mean the change notification when adding element to ResourceDictionary, when the ResourceDictionary is set (the first time) it should be notified in the property changed callback. That can be achieved when `ResourceDictioanary` was changed from `null` (the default) to an instance I set in XAML, but that way it's not very convenient. Without explicitly declaring the tags `ResourceDictionary` and using a default instance of ResourceDictionary, an exception of null is thrown. You should try exactly the code to understand it.

Comment: @SnowballTwo At least I understand almost what's wrong and currently accept an ugly solution of explicitly specifying the tags `ResourceDictionary` but what I want is how to make it more convenient (no `ResourceDictionary` tag but still with change notification). What you said seemed to try to explain things but that's very close to what I know (and already said here), I would like a solution and looks like you don't likely have an idea. Thanks any way.

Comment: I'm sorry for this misunderstanding, i simply wanted to say "it's impossible", according to your last sentence in the post.